# Почему setBounds не учитывает максимальный зумм и отступы?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

При создании карты указываю максимальный зум так и там же задаю `setDefaultMargin`:

```js
var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 7,
            maxZoom: 12
        });
map.margin.setDefaultMargin([0,600,0,0]);
```

Однако когда делаю `map.setBounds(map.geoObjects.getBounds());` ни отступы, ни зум не учитываются.
С зумом борюсь так:

```
if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(16); // максимальный зум
```

А что делать с отступами - вообще не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maxZoom это опция и её нужно задавать так:

```
var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 7
    }, {
        maxZoom: 12
    });
```

Comment: Да - действительно - так работает.
А как быть с отступами? Признаюсь честно я даже не сильно понял из документации как они считаются.
Но я пробую выводить проверить устанавливаются они:
margin.getOffset() возвращает [-300, 0] (кстати почему не 600?)
margin.getMargin() - [0, 600, 0, 0]

Но видимого эффекта не вижу.

Comment: В песочнице есть пример как использовать отступы https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/margin_manager . Также обратите внимание, что метод setBounds по умолчанию отступы не учитывает. Для того чтобы он их учитывал нужно передать опцию useMapMargin map.setBounds([[60,-40], [20,60]], { useMapMargin: true,}) Документация: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__setBounds